# Safari on ipad wont open .docx and .eps?

Tags: ipad, safari

Having issue with safari on ipad as it wont open .docx and .eps from my website. Can someone suggest me if I need to install any any plugin to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Changed MIME Type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" to make it work for .docx.